# End Time of Scheduler for Thread Group Thread Group is in the past in Jmeter sheduler mode testing

Tags: jmeter

Unable to run Jmeter test plan in scheduler mode in distributed testing.

We are using Bamboo pipeline with dockerized Jmeter, able to run in normal mode successfully however when tried the same test plan in scheduler mode facing an error with 'Endtime' value.

The current test plan after setting (scheduler mode is checked, forever is checked, delay is set to 0 and duration is set to 1800 seconds) and Start and End time kept as it is.

Jmeter version: 3.1

```
 <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
    <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1518153310000</longProp>
    <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1518153310000</longProp>
    <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.1800">1800</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">0</stringProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
```

When run the test: getting below error "Error occurred compiling the tree:
End Time (2018/02/09 05:15:10) of Scheduler for Thread Group Thread Group 
is in the past, fix value of End Time field" though scheduler, forever is true

```
root@081459cc5d34:/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin# jmeter -n -t 
/home/new.jmx
Writing log file to: /jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/jmeter.log
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /home/new.jmx
Starting the test @ Fri Feb 09 05:35:49 UTC 2018 (1518154549080)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
Error occurred compiling the tree:
End Time (2018/02/09 05:15:10) of Scheduler for Thread Group Thread Group 
is in 
the past, fix value of End Time field,
see log file for more details
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 
Max: 
-9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Feb 09 05:35:49 UTC 2018 (1518154549166)
... end of run
```

Note: able to run the same test plan when set 'start and end time' by removing values for duration, delay.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to overcome issue in the latest Jmeter 4.0 release, our tests are running successfully.